# Finding Trend and Seasonality on Hourly Time Series Energy Data

Tags: pandas, time-series, trend

[image]

Hello, I am new in statistics and I am trying to find trend and seasonality on the energy consumption dataset by using pandas. How can I able to find those with respect to hour. I tried
`decomposition = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(RTC_data['Electricity Usage (MWh)'], model='additive')` but getting ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a PeriodIndex or a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None

Comment: What kind of seasonality are you trying to add? E.g. daily seasonality, weekly seasonality, yearly seasonality? You need to tell `seasonal_decompose()` which kind through the `period` argument. See also: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html

Comment: do you need `period=1`?

Comment: I actually don't know what period means but I want seasonality on daily.